# Add edit option for text inside <li> element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to change `li.innerHtml` when I click `<li>` it creates new input where I can change `<li>`'s text but after that I want to save it, it does not work well.
I need to change each `<li>` text when I click that `<li>`

```js
function setText(elem, text){
 elem.innerHTML += text;
}

var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];


for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.addEventListener("click", changeText);
 setText(li, arr[i]);
 var ul = document.createElement("ul");
 document.body.appendChild(ul);
 ul.appendChild(li);
}

var input = 0;

function changeText(){
 input = document.createElement("input");
 input.addEventListener("blur", saveText);
 document.body.appendChild(input);
 input.value = this.innerHTML;
}


function saveText(){
    li.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50247904/6804958) answer ?

Comment: Yeah,  George Bailey but i hope i can find another solutions too

Comment: You could just make the `li`-element editable by setting `contentEditable` to true. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an `ID` when creating the `li` and then add this `id` as a data attribute on `input` so you would know which input was changed and which `li` to update.

Here

```js
function setText(elem, text){
 elem.innerHTML += text;
}

var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];


for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.id = i;
 li.addEventListener("click", changeText);
 setText(li, arr[i]);
 var ul = document.createElement("ul");
 document.body.appendChild(ul);
 ul.appendChild(li);
}

var input = 0;

function changeText(event){
 input = document.createElement("input");
 input.addEventListener("blur", saveText);
 document.body.appendChild(input);
   
  input.setAttribute("data-liID", event.target.id);
 input.value = this.innerHTML;
}


function saveText(event){
   document.getElementById(event.srcElement.getAttribute("data-liID")).innerHTML = this.value
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function as below

```js
function setText(elem, text){
 elem.innerHTML += text;
}

var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.addEventListener("click", changeText);
 setText(li, arr[i]);
 ul.appendChild(li);
}

var input = 0;

function changeText(){
 input = document.createElement("input");
 input.addEventListener("change", saveText);
 document.body.appendChild(input);
 input.value = this.innerHTML;
}


function saveText(){
 var li=ul.children;
 for (var liElement in li) {
  li[liElement].innerHTML = this.value;
 }
    
}
```

Comment: Ab Mishra you didi not get by right way i need each li change only its text

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is, that `li` in `saveText()` is undefined. You have to reference it to the `input` somehow.

Also be aware that you are creating an `ul` container for each seperate `li` element. I do not know if that is on purpose. Yet it might be handy, if you see example two.

### Example using data-attribute

Here is an example on how to do it with a data-attribute using your code with some slight changes (see comments):

```js
//An array holding potential li-elements
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

//Creates an input element to change the text for the li element with
function changeText(){
 var tIndex = this.getAttribute('data-index'); //The index we gave to the li-element on creating
 var input = document.querySelector("input[data-index='" + tIndex + "']"); //Check if the input exists already

 if(!input){
  input = document.createElement('input'); //Make it local
  input.setAttribute('data-index', this.getAttribute('data-index')); //We use this to find the correct li-element in saveText
  input.addEventListener('blur', saveText);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.value = this.innerHTML;
 }
};

function setText(elem, text){
 elem.innerHTML += text;
};

function saveText(){
 var li = document.querySelector("li[data-index='" + this.getAttribute('data-index') + "']"); //Now with the index we can find our element
 li.innerHTML = this.value;
};

window.onload = function(){
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.setAttribute('data-index', i); //We use this to find the correct li-element in saveText
  li.addEventListener('click', changeText);
  setText(li, arr[i]);
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
  ul.appendChild(li);
 }
}
```

### Example using ul as parentNode for both

Another way is to add the `input` to the `ul`, so you can just access its parent:

```js
//An array holding potential li-elements
    var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

    //Creates an input element to change the text for the li element with
    function changeText(){
     var input = this.parentNode.querySelector('input'); //Check if exists yet

     if(!input){
      input = document.createElement('input'); 
      input.addEventListener('blur', saveText);
      this.parentNode.appendChild(input); //We add the input to the ul instead of the body
      input.value = this.innerHTML;
     }
    };

    function setText(elem, text){
     elem.innerHTML += text;
    };

    function saveText(){
     var li = this.parentNode.firstChild; //firstchild is the li in this case
     li.innerHTML = this.value;
    };

    window.onload = function(){
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.addEventListener('click', changeText);
      setText(li, arr[i]);
      var ul = document.createElement('ul');
      document.body.appendChild(ul);
      ul.appendChild(li);
     }
    }
```

### Example using contentEditable

It can also be done by making the `li` elements editable:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

window.onload = function(){
 var ul = document.createElement('ul');
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = arr[i];
  li.contentEditable = true;
  ul.appendChild(li);
 };
 document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```